# Issue while saving serialize java object to Db

Tags: java, dom, serialization

I have Java class configuration which is serializable.

I want to create an instance of configuration which contains data of type string,Document (org.w3c.dom.Document) and save it into Db which is of type BLOB.

But when i am going to save it into the DB it's throwing exception :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.w3c.tidy.DOMElementImpl
```

My configuration class is:

```
public class Configuration extends Tag implements Serializable{

    private Document doc = null ;
    private String checkpoint=null; 

}
```

I have used following code when saving configuration object to DB :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(configuration);
byte[] confBytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

I am first converting it to byte array and then saving.

can anyone help me to get out of this issue..

Comment: Serialization requires the full chain being serializable... and DocumentImpl does not seem to be serializable.

Comment: is there any way to do that??

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. You should be very careful when serializing objects into a database, especially in the case your code just uses an interface (org.w3c.Document) and the implementation is determined at runtime. I'd convert the org.w3c.Document in a plain String and serialize the string (or directly place it in a VARCHAR or CLOB column)...

Comment: I assume, that DomElementImpl, is used as an inner class here, and is not Serializable itself.

Although, to find out more a Stack Trace would be helpful.

In the end, what home recommends is probably the safest and fastest solution.

Comment: You should then declare the non serializable object as "transient", and then recreate it upon reloading the object.

Comment: But if I declare non serializable object as "transient" then my data will be lost then how to recreate that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.w3c.tidy.DOMElementImpl
```

This is saying that the `DOMElementImpl` class is not marked as `Serializable`.  Even though your `Configuration` class implements `Serializable`, all of the fields in your class need to do so as well.  I assume that `Document` is the field that is the problem.  To quote from [this serialization tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm):

> Notice that for a class to be serialized successfully, two conditions must be met:
>
> - The class must implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
> - All of the fields in the class must be serializable. If a field is not serializable, it must be marked transient.

Looking at the [`DOMElementImpl` class](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/DOMElementImpl.html), it does implement `Serializable`.  If you need to serialize this to a database then you will need to export it to another class before storing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to bypass these serialization issues with [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/)